# Need to store user inputted values into columnwise format [MIPS]

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write a program that will enter a user's value rowwise and store those values columnwise in a 3 by 4 matrix. I tried getting the values stored using the columnwise formula derived in my lecture. However, I think there's somewhere I'm failing. My program below:

```
inputRowWise:
li $t1, 0               # colIndex = 0
li $t2, 3               # rowSize = 3
li $t3, 4               # colSize = 4

addToIndexColumnsOuter:
    bge $t1, $t3, return        # Branch if we've finished adding values in this col.
    li $t0, 0           # rowIndex = 0 

addToIndexColumnsInner:
    bge $t0, $t2, rowEnd        # Branch when we finished adding the rows       
    mul $t4, $t1, $t2       # $t4 = colIndex * rowSize 
    add $t4, $t4, $t0       # + rowIndex
    mul $t4, $t4, 4         # * Data_size.
    add $t4, $t4, $a1       # + Base address.

    la $a0, enterNum
    li $v0, 4
    syscall             # Print the message.

    li $v0, 5
    syscall             # get the user value.

    sw $v0, 0($t4)          # Store the value given by user into this index position.

    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Move the index + 1

    j addToIndexColumnsInner    # If we are finished inserting the values into index, get a new row.

rowEnd:
    addi $t1, $t1, 1        # Add up the colIndex index.
    j addToIndexColumnsOuter
return:
jr $ra

.data 
.align 2
matrix: .space 48
enterNum: .asciiz "Please enter a number: "
```

My end result ends up becoming for any 12 ints inputted: [an array with values stored rowwise instread of columnwise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Ee7.png)

Comment: Your question is missing a [mcve] of what actually happens when you try running it.  Be more specific than *I think there's somewhere I'm failing*.

Comment: Your picture of the MARS debugger doesn't show what order you typed the inputs.  There's 1..7 in increasing addresses (along the first 2 rows, for a normal row-major storage format), then `0x59`, then `1..4`.  Depending what you typed, that makes sense.